# Wine: Error when starting a exe

Tags: linux-mint, wine

I have installed Wine without root access, from a `tar.gz`-file.
When I want to start an exe file, there are some errors.

Here are some of them:

```
000d:err:wincodecs:PngEncoder_CreateInstance Trying to save PNG picture, but PNG support is not compiled in.

000d:fixme:ole:CoCreateInstanceEx no instance created for interface {00000103-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94} of class {27949969-876a-41d7-9447-568f6a35a4dc}, hres is 0x80004005

000d:err:menubuilder:convert_to_native_icon error 0x80004005 creating bitmap encoder

000d:err:wincodecs:PngEncoder_CreateInstance Trying to save PNG picture, but PNG support is not compiled in.

000d:fixme:ole:CoCreateInstanceEx no instance created for interface {00000103-a8f2-4877-ba0a-fd2b6645fb94} of class {27949969-876a-41d7-9447-568f6a35a4dc}, hres is 0x80004005

000d:err:menubuilder:convert_to_native_icon error 0x80004005 creating bitmap encoder

000d:err:wincodecs:PngEncoder_CreateInstance Trying to save PNG picture, but PNG support is not compiled in.
```

Answer (score 0):

The location of `$PREFIX/lib/wine` is **hardcoded** in `libwine.so.1.0` during compile time and AFAIK cannot be changed. If you're unable to install a binary Wine package normally, i.e. using the root account, you could try compiling it but then it will require lots of development libraries and headers.